# Django: m2m_changed not fired when end of relation is deleted

Tags: python, django, many-to-many, signals, django-orm

**NOTICE**: due to production environment constraints, I must stick to `django-1.4` for the moment.

I've just made a test to see whether I can hook onto an event when ManyToMany changes.

I have a `Group` model that holds several `Item` objects. Whenever the items change in any group, I want to do something with concerned Group` instances.

```
from django.db import models
    from django.db.models.signals import m2m_changed, post_delete, pre_delete

class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(to=Item)    

def items_changed(signal, sender, action, instance, reverse, model, pk_set, using, **kwargs):
    print str(signal)
    print action, instance, reverse, pk_set

m2m_changed.connect(items_changed, sender=Group.items.through)
```

If I change the `items` list on a `Group` instance, I the `m2m_changed` event is obviously fired.

```
>>> from sandbox.core.models import Group, Item
>>> item, created = Item.objects.get_or_create(name='f')
>>> g = Group.objects.get(pk=1)
>>> g.items.add(item)
pre_add Group object False set([5])
post_add Group object False set([5])
>>> g.items.remove(item)
pre_remove Group object False set([5])
post_remove Group object False set([5])
```

Now, when I remove the `Item` end of the relation, nothing happens, however, the relation table entry is correctly deleted.

```
>>> item.delete()
```

I tried connecting to the delete signal of the m2m through table, but apparently, signals are not fired for the automatic relation tables.

Connected like this in my `models.py` module:

```
def group_items_pre_delete(signal, sender, instance, using, **kwargs):
    print 'pre_delete', instance

def group_items_post_delete(signal, sender, instance, using, **kwargs):
    print 'post_delete', instance

pre_delete.connect(group_items_pre_delete, sender=Group.items.through)
post_delete.connect(group_items_post_delete, sender=Group.items.through)
```

The solution I have for now is to check manually for changes. The models are exposed through a REST API, so I can do this when an update request ends (but I would have liked it to be automated through the signals).

Are those "missing" signals fired in any newer version of Django?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Could you do a pre/post_delete connect on the Item object
`post_delete.connect(items_deleted, sender=Items)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a bug, not fixed yet:
https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/17688