# Django: No m2m_changed signal when one side of a many-to-many is deleted?

Tags: django, django-signals, manytomanyfield

I want to trigger some behaviour whenever a many-to-many relationship changes, but I'm unsure what signal setup is best for capturing changes to that relationship that come about due to the deletion of one side of the relationship. `m2m_changed` does not seem to fire in this case, nor do the regular `post_save` and `post_delete` signals seem to be applicable to the `through` model?

My current solution is to listen to `pre_delete` on the models which compose either side of the relationship and then clear the relationship within that signal in order to trigger a `m2m_changed`. I'm surprised that I have to do this though, and feel I've got something wrong.

**What am I missing here? And if I am not missing anything why is this necessary (ie why is no such signal fired by default)?**

#### Code example:

```
class ResearchField(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=200)

class Researcher(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    research_fields = models.ManyToManyField(ResearchField, blank=True)

@receiver(m2m_changed, sender=Researcher.research_fields.through)
def research_fields_changed(sender, instance, action, **kwargs):
    # need to do something important here
    print('m2m_changed', action)

volcanology = ResearchField.objects.create(name='Volcanology')
researcher = Researcher.objects.create(name='A. Volcanologist')

researcher.research_fields.add(volcanology)
>>> m2m_changed pre_add
>>> m2m_changed post_add
```

This `m2m_changed` signal fires as expected when the relationship is removed from either side:

```
researcher.research_fields.remove(volcanology)
# or equally volcanology.researcher_set.remove(researcher)
>>> m2m_changed pre_remove
>>> m2m_changed post_remove
```

However no `pre_remove` or `post_remove` `m2m_changed` signals fire if I simply delete one side of the relationship, despite the Django `delete` output indicating that an instance of the `through` model was removed:

```
# with the relationship intact
volcanology.delete()
>>> (2, {'ResearchField': 1, 'Researcher_research_fields': 1})
```

At this point I tried:

```
@receiver(post_delete, sender=Researcher.research_fields.through)
def through_model_deleted(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    print('through model deleted')
```

But this never fires?

As a result my current solution is to have:

```
@receiver(pre_delete, sender=ResearchField)
def research_field_deleted(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.researcher_set.clear()
```

To custom enforce that when `Researcher.research_fields.through` objects are being deleted via a cascade from a deleted `ResearchField` the `m2m_changed` signal will fire after all. However as I said at the top it feels like I've missed something that this is necessary?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django: m2m\_changed not fired when end of relation is deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31937208/django-m2m-changed-not-fired-when-end-of-relation-is-deleted)

Answer (score 3):

I missed this when posting my question but it seems this is an open bug in Django https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/17688.